# Angular form - send only changed fields

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a web client that works with a settings web API with angular. 
There are a lot of settings and they are all optional. If I send a setting, it should be saved. Settings that are not sent should not change.

The requirement is to have one **Save Changes** button for all the settings.

I wonder if there is some way in Angular to implement this.

I thought about not using HTML `form` and collecting the data and creating an ajax request by myself but then I will lose the validation mechanism (that is working well with Angular-UI validate).

I thought about splitting the form into little forms and submiting only the forms where `ng-dirty` is not false, but this can cause a partial save if some requests will fail (and this is against the requirement).

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Angular documentation there is an example that covers ng-copy to implement a reset function.

http://docs.angularjs.org/cookbook/advancedform

During submit you could compare your starting model(master copy) to the changed/submitted object (changed copy) and only submit the changed items (or just delete those that are the same/unchanged).

Diff the copy and master with 
http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/object-difference.html 
This needs extra work to handle arrays. 
Or convert to JSON and diff the JSON
https://github.com/benjamine/JsonDiffPatch

Comment: this is not what I was looking for, but I guess this means that angular doesn't offer this functionality out of the box. thank you.

Comment: That's reinventing the wheel - angular FormController and ngModel already perform dirty checks, add classes and store this info in $scope. See answer from r4w87173

Comment: @ArturBodera What if I want to automate this process? It seems like I need to keep track of input names and model attributes. (I'm actually asking).

Comment: You could just forEach() through them, sounds trivial.

Answer (score 18):

You can check if the form or any named field is modified before submission. If the form has a name and your inputs have names like:

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input name="input1">
</form>
```

In the controller you will have access to the object `$scope.myForm` and `$scope.myForm.input1`, and these objects will have a `$dirty` property which is true if the original value was modified by the user.